# controlling orientation changes from within a subview

Tags: ios, xcode, orientation

Have a very large program where there is always a superview that just encompasses a custom segment controller.  This view sits at the top of screen and controls navigation in several ways.

So the problem arose in only a selected few view controllers where everything was 100% programmaticly created.  Essentially CGRect are not being defined in the property dynamic coordinates.  But are not being recalculated on orientation change.  Does anyone have a simple way to control this in the subview?  I'm about to code something in the superview to pass to orientation to other subviews.. but there has to be a better way.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of pointers:

You can use auto-resizing masks to determine what happens to your views when their bounds change (ie, when the orientation changes). So `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` means your view will 'stretch' proportionally with the superview when the bounds are changed. `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin` means your view will effectively be right-aligned, as the left margin will adjust according to the width, etc etc.

Sometimes auto-resizing masks aren't enough - perhaps you have to change the view's content on an orientation, or do a complex animation. In this case, you use the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` method in your view controller. Your subviews might have a custom `adjustForOrientation` method that you've written that you can trigger when `willAnimateRotation...` is called.

Finally, on iOS 5 you can actually nest view controllers inside of view controllers, in which case orientation events get passed through automatically...but this is probably needlessly complex for what you're trying to do.

Comment: that has some working.. I can't seem to get any of the other methods to shoot out even an NSLog.  This is strictly IOS5, but I probably don't want to go in and nest all the VC's.  Do you have to have an example method that will fire in a subview on rotation?

Comment: You can just write your own method, and then call it yourself in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`. The nice thing is all the calls you make inside of that method will be animated themselves to the appropriate duration.